# How do I pull error codes from my Kawasaki motorcycle?

Tags: motorcycle, cel, electronic-control-module, kawasaki

I have an FI light on my Kawasaki motorcycle that is 2002 or newer.

How do I get the error codes so I can troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ## How do I pull error codes from my Kawasaki motorcycle?

**Here are the instructions to pull error codes from your 2001 or later Kawasaki street motorcycle.**

**Step 1**
Pull off your seat and near the battery negative terminal there will be a self diagnosis lead coming out of a connector.  The wire is yellow.  It looks like this.

[image]
**Step 2**
Get a wire, one with alligator clips on either side is what I use.  Makes things a bit easier.

Attach the alligator clip to the yellow wire

**Step 3**
Turn the ignition switch to the 'ON' position and wait a few seconds for the start procedure to complete.

**Step 4**
Attach the lead to the batter negative (ground)

**Step 5**
Watch your FI light.  It will begin to blink long and short flashes.

**Step 6**
You will now interpret the flashes into a numerical value using the following table.

[image]

**Interpreting Error Codes**
The FI light will be flashing long and short blinks.

The long blinks represent 10 through 90.

The short blinks represent 1-9

If you get three long flashes followed by 4 short the error code would 34 and you can reference on the table.

**Kawasaki Dirt Bikes**

***This technique does not apply to Kawasaki dirt bikes.***

If you have additional information regarding Kawasaki error codes in various dealer modes, please please message and provide links and I will add it to this post.

*Images pulled from ocmoto.com*